# Intricate Word Counting in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to find the AVERAGE WORD COUNT within a spreadsheet given a particular name.  An example would be:

> Author   Words
>
> Person1 this is an example
>
> Person1 so is this
>
> Person1 this is too
>
> Person2 those examples suck
>
> Person2 this one is better ...

I have a function that will count the words:

```
Function intWordCount(rng As Range) As Integer
    intWordCount = UBound(Split(rng.Value, " "), 1) + 1
End Function
```

I'm at a loss on how to loop through the list given a name (PersonX), sum the count of the words, then divide by the total per person.

Hopefully that was clear...

Thanks,
Stu

Comment: You can loop through every cell in the sheet and add to a counter  when the cell matches your criteria This page should get you started on checking every cell in a range:  [Count words](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/count-words.html)

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to alter your code to handle more than one cell; the way I went with is with a `For Each` loop to go through each row in the range.

```
For Each Row In rng.Rows
    ...
Next
```

The next step is to check if we want a row comparing the first column to some value `str`.

```
For Each Row In rng.Rows
    If (Row.Cells(1, 1).Value = str) Then
        ...
    End If
Next
```

Putting those two pieces together with your original function and you get a function like this.

```
Function avgWordCount(rng As Range, str As String) As Double
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim wordCount As Long

    Dim Row As Range
    For Each Row In rng.Rows
        If (Row.Cells(1, 1).Value = str) Then
            counter = counter + 1
            wordCount = wordCount + UBound(Split(Row.Cells(1, 2).Value, " "), 1) + 1
        End If
    Next

    avgWordCount = wordCount / counter
End Function
```

It can be called using a cell reference or a static string.

[image: Results]